# Vuetify - Hide Navigation drawer during transition

Tags: vue.js, vuetify.js

I have a `v-navigation-drawer` on a couple pages in my web app. I also am using 'animate.css' to transition between views. When I transition between views the navigation drawer is shown even if its not been selected.

[Here is a 15 second video showing what happens.](https://screencast-o-matic.com/watch/cqVVDmrR08)

Any ideas on how I could hide the drawer from showing during transition?

Here is my code.. This is one of the views with my drawer.. I've included the `navigation drawer` as a component and called it `side_drawer`

```
<template>
  <v-container fill-height>
    <v-layout row wrap>
      <v-flex xs10 class="mx-auto">

        <v-layout row wrap align-right>
          <v-flex xs12>
            <side_drawer></side_drawer>
          </v-flex>
        </v-layout>

          <v-spacer></v-spacer>
          <v-card class="pa-4" id="devIds">
            <v-card-title>
              <v-icon class="my_dark_purple_text">help_outline</v-icon>
              <h1 class="title oswald my_dark_purple_text pl-2">SETUP INSTRUCTIONS</h1>
            </v-card-title>

          <v-expansion-panel>
            <v-expansion-panel-content>
              <div slot="header" class="subheading">How do I know my orders are getting to Amazon?</div>
              <v-divider></v-divider>
              <v-card>

                <v-list>
                  <v-list-tile>
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                      <v-icon color="purple darken-4">adjust</v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                      <div class="subheading">Once the order has been paid, the order status will 
                      transition to "Open". This should take less than 1 minute. At this point you will be able to see your order on Amazon.
                      </div>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                  </v-list-tile>
                </v-list>   

                <v-list three-line>  
                  <v-list-tile>
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                      <v-icon color="purple darken-4">adjust</v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                      <div class="subheading">The next order status is "Fulfilled". This is when Amazon has shipped your item, provided a tracking number, and we've notified your customer that their order has shipped. Your
                      order will transition to "Fulfilled" typically in 1 - 5 business days depending on the shipping rate that was selected.
                      </div>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                  </v-list-tile>

                </v-list>       

              </v-card>
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>          

          <v-expansion-panel>
            <v-expansion-panel-content class="purple_header">
              <div slot="header" class="subheading">
                Amazon will only accept orders that use the shipping rates you set up here in FBA Shipping.
              </div>
              <v-card>
                <v-list>
                  <v-list-tile>
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                      <v-icon color="purple darken-4">adjust</v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                      <div class="subheading">If you only sell FBA products, delete any other shipping rates you have set up in Shopify.</div>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                  </v-list-tile>

                  <v-list-tile>
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                      <v-icon color="purple darken-4">adjust</v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                      <div class="subheading">If you sell FBA products AND non-FBA products, you'll need to set up weight based shipping rates. Please see the setup video here:
                      <a href="https://youtu.be/L4HOTJm5hQQ" target="_blank" class="my_dark_purple_text" >Weight Based Workaround Video</a>
                      </div>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                  </v-list-tile>

                </v-list>
              </v-card>
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>

          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-expansion-panel>
            <v-expansion-panel-content>
              <div slot="header" class="subheading">Make sure your Shopify SKU matches your Amazon SKU</div>
              <v-divider></v-divider>
              <v-card>

                <v-list>
                  <v-list-tile>
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                      <v-icon color="purple darken-4">adjust</v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                      <div class="subheading">Ensure your Shopify product SKUs match the SKUs on Amazon (not ASIN or UPC).</div>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                  </v-list-tile>
                </v-list>       

              </v-card>
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>

          <v-expansion-panel>
            <v-expansion-panel-content class="purple_header">
              <div slot="header" class="subheading">"Inventory Managed by" should be set to FBA Shipping</div>
              <v-card>
                <v-list>
                  <v-list-tile>
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                      <v-icon color="purple darken-4">adjust</v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                      <div class="subheading">On your product page make sure to set "Inventory Managed by" to FBA Shipping. You can do this one product at a time
                      or for all your products at once using Shopify's built-in bulk editor.</div>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                  </v-list-tile>
                </v-list> 
              </v-card>
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>

          <v-divider></v-divider>

          <v-expansion-panel>
            <v-expansion-panel-content>
              <div slot="header" class="subheading">Automatic or manual fulfillment your choice</div>
              <v-divider></v-divider>
              <v-card>

                <v-list>
                  <v-list-tile>
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                      <v-icon color="purple darken-4">adjust</v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                      <div class="subheading">You can set orders to be automatically fulfilled in your Shopify checkout settings. If you don't set that up, you'll need to request fulfillment on each order.</div>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                  </v-list-tile>
                </v-list>       

              </v-card>
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>

          <v-expansion-panel>
            <v-expansion-panel-content class="purple_header">
              <div slot="header" class="subheading">If this setup takes more than 5 minutes please call!</div>
              <v-card>
                <v-list>
                  <v-list-tile>
                    <v-list-tile-action>
                      <v-icon color="purple darken-4">adjust</v-icon>
                    </v-list-tile-action>
                    <v-list-tile-content>
                      <div class="subheading">Total time to setup should be 5 minutes or less, if you're struggling with these instructions please give us a call at 704.489.3578.</div>
                    </v-list-tile-content>
                  </v-list-tile>
                </v-list> 
              </v-card>
            </v-expansion-panel-content>
          </v-expansion-panel>

        </v-card>
      </v-flex>
    </v-layout>
  </v-container>  
</template>

<script>
import side_drawer from '../components/side_drawer.vue';
import {dataShare} from '../packs/application.js';

export default {
  components: {
    side_drawer
  },
  data: function() {
    return {
      drawer: false
    };
  }
};
</script>

<style>

.purple_header {
  background-color: #E1BEE7 !important;
}  

</style>
```

And then this is the `navigation-drawer` itself.

```
<template>
  <div>

    <v-btn
      dark
      fab
      medium
      color="green lighten-1"
      class="push_right"
      @click="drawer = !drawer">
      <v-icon>settings</v-icon>
    </v-btn>

    <v-navigation-drawer
      v-model="drawer"
      absolute
      temporary
      hide-overlay
      right>

      <v-list>
        <v-list-tile>
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title class="title mont">Settings & Help</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>

      <v-divider></v-divider>

      <v-list dense>

        <v-list-tile @click="sendToCreds">  
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title class="subheading mont">Amazon Credentials</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>

          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon color="purple darken-3">settings</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-list-tile @click="sendToSpeeds">  
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title class="subheading mont">Shipping Speeds</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>

          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon color="purple darken-3">local_shipping</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-list-tile @click="sendToInstructions">  
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title class="subheading mont">Instructions</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>

          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon color="purple darken-3">info</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-list-tile @click="goToFAQ">  
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title class="subheading mont">F.A.Q.</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>

          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon color="purple darken-3">help</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
        </v-list-tile>

        <v-list-tile @click="goToSetupVideos">  
          <v-list-tile-content>
            <v-list-tile-title class="subheading mont">Setup Videos</v-list-tile-title>
          </v-list-tile-content>

          <v-list-tile-action>
            <v-icon color="purple darken-3">ondemand_video</v-icon>
          </v-list-tile-action>
        </v-list-tile>
      </v-list>

    </v-navigation-drawer>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import {dataShare} from '../packs/application.js';
import axios from 'axios';

export default {
  data: function() {
    return {
      drawer: false,
    };
  },
  methods: {
    goToSetupVideos() {
      window.open('https://youtu.be/ehjrrJLG_xs',
                  '_blank');
    },
    goToFAQ() {
      window.open('http://bytestand.com/fba-shipping-faq/',
                  '_blank');
    },
    sendToCreds() {
      dataShare.$emit('whereToGo', 'amazon_credentials');
    },
    sendToSpeeds() {
      dataShare.$emit('whereToGo', 'speeds');
    },
    sendToInstructions() {
      dataShare.$emit('whereToGo', 'instructions');
    }  
  }
};

</script>
```

Comment: The drawer is present, but off screen. As your panel slides to the left, the drawer slides on to the screen. Put a v-show on the side-drawer component.

Comment: @JacksonMiller thanks man! yep I tried that.. it kills the drawer transition, makes it jumpy. but maybe that's my only alternative..